# Why can't I copy/convert a List<Set<String>> into a SortedMap<Set<String>,Integer>?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I want to copy my elements from a `List<Set<String>>` into a `SortedMap<Set<String>,Integer>`,
but I always get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable. (or HashMap could be a TreeSet too, vice versa)
```

Some places I've been reading say it isn't possible, but is this correct?

I can't believe I can't copy a original List or Set into a Map.

This is what I have tried:

```
List<Set<String> > tempnewOut= new ArrayList<>(); 
SortedMap<Set<String>,Integer> freqSetsWithCount= new TreeMap<>(); 
for (Set<String> set : tempnewOut) 
{ 
    freqSetsWithCount.put(set, 0); 
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have, because without that, we can't really help you...

Comment: List<Set<String> > tempnewOut= new ArrayList<>();                  SortedMap<Set<String>,Integer> freqSetsWithCount= new TreeMap<>();          for (Set<String> set : tempnewOut) {
            
            freqSetsWithCount.put(set, 0);                                      
                            
        }

Comment: @GaborToth seriously... can you read the comment you have posted? Please edit your question and add your code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that you use as a key in a `TreeMap` (one of the implementations of interface `SortedMap`) must either implement interface `Comparable`, or you must create the `TreeMap` by providing a `Comparator` to the constructor.

You're trying to use a `HashSet<String>` for the keys. `HashSet` doesn't implement `Comparable`, and you're not supplying a `Comparator`, so you get a `ClassCastException`.

One solution is to create the `TreeMap` by passing it a `Comparator` to the constructor. You'll have to implement the `compare` method of the `Comparator` to specify how the sets should be sorted in the map.

```
List<Set<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comparator<Set<String>> comparator = new Comparator<Set<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Set<String> o1, Set<String> o2) {
        // TODO: Implement your logic to compare the sets
    }
};

SortedMap<Set<String>, Integer> set = new TreeMap<>(comparator);

// TODO: Fill the set
```

Comment: how can i easily define the compare method on two Set of strings?

Comment: You're using these sets as keys in a `SortedMap`. That means you must have some idea about how to sort these sets: if you have two sets, how do you determine which comes first in the sort order? Is it the set with the fewest elements, or do you have some other criteria? It's up to you to decide this. Without knowing how you want to sort the sets, I can't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

A SortedMap is, as the name implies, a Map of sorted elements. To be able to sort elements in this manner, the Comparable interface has to be implemented on the elements inside it.

The List of Sets that you're working with, doesn't implement the Comparable interface, so you aren't able to simply put the Set from your List inside the Set of your SortedMap without converting them to something that implements Comparable I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the `Set` interface does not extend the `Comparable` interface. But in order to use an object as a Key in a sortedMap it needs to implement `Comparable`.

That's only logical, you cannot sort anything if you do not know if one instance is greater, equal or less than the other ...

Like the others I suggest you use the Integer as Key if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

SortedMap requires that the key ( your case the hashset) implements the comparable interface to sort it.

Hashset doesnt implement it so it cant to typecasted in the SortedMap implementation.
you could write you own Set which extends hashmap and implements comparable to make it work.

if you want to sort it by the integer simply switch the key and value

```
SortedMap<Integer,Set<String>>
```

the javadoc is pretty clear to me

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html